# How do I get inside this building near Mzinchaleft?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I found the following building near Mzinchaleft, there is one lever in the middle of it and some gears in the corners. But I can't find any obvious way to get inside it, the gates on all four sides don't seem to open.

How do I get inside this building?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Later in the main quest, you make it to the underground area of Blackreach. These are elevators back and forth to the cavern, accessible from inside. Once you exit using one of these elevators, you can activate a lever and the gate will stay open so you can use it as an entrance from then on.